# android app open from push override locale language

Tags: android, push-notification, localization

i am building a multi lang app i override the locale lang in Application class

```
public void setLanguage(String language) {
    Locale myLocale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = myLocale;
    config.setLayoutDirection(myLocale);
    getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    if (config.getLayoutDirection() == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL) {
        systemRtl = true;
    }
}
```

this works great, but when i am opening my app from push notification on Nexus P6 with the locale not getting override, and opens the app with the phone default locale. i have tried this with samsung s6, lg g3, and meizu mx4 pro, and it works correctly, only on the nexus this problem.

i have searched the net but not found a solution.

can any one help?

Comment: the nexus 6P runs on android 7.0

Comment: Does the phone use multi Locale? Its new feature in 7.0 and might be causing this behavior

Comment: hi thank you for the reply.. how can i check this?